# My Galaxy S3 has a white screen with grey lines

Tags: hardware, touchscreen

My Galaxy S3 has a white screen with grey lines and nothing is working. I don't know if the internal memory is overloaded or if the issue is in the hardware. Can it be fixed or not?

[image: photo of device]

Comment: Did this start suddenly? What were the last things you did (that might have led to the current situation)? Is the device rooted, and did you apply any changes involving "root powers" recently?